# Property does not exist on type 'never'. Why is this an error, and not a warning?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
let count: number | undefined | null = 10;
count = null;
let result: string | undefined | null = count?.toFixed(2);
console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
```

This gives the following error:

> error TS2339: Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'never'.

However the following code compiles and (as expected) writes to the console:

```
let count: number | undefined | null = 10;
if (1) {
    count = null;
}
let result: string | undefined | null = count?.toFixed(2);
console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
```

> Result: undefined

OK, I got it, in the first example the compiler statically infers that `count` is always `null`. It makes it worst, that the compiler's static analysis capability is really poor if in the second example (where the argument of the `if` statement is a constant) it is not capable to get to the same conclusion...

**Question**

Is there a concrete theoretical/design reason behind this error message (so I am missing something) or is this just a bad decision (to elevate this lint like thing to an error), and make it worst with almost zero static analysis capability (in the second example)?

Comment: Regarding the design decision to treat this as an error, it can be argued that it is a useful feature because it catches potential type errors early in the development process. However, it can also be frustrating in cases where the programmer is aware of the possible types and wants to suppress the error. In such cases, it is possible to use a type assertion to override the inferred type

Comment: I noticed that it won't narrow it down for things like `if(2<3)`. Probably because people rarely used anything like that, so it's not useful to add for the analysis.
For the `never`, I think it's because using `?` on `someType | null | undefined` will exclude `null` and `undefined` and focus on the properties of `someType`. If the original is always `null`, after excluding null, the remaining type is `never`. While `null?.toFixed` does not cause a runtime error, there is a problem of typing, as it expects something with a `toFixed` property.

Comment: @qrsngky it narrows `if (true)` which is also not an often used line... so we now totally have no explanation why exactly `if (1)` is so hard. Anyway my point was not why it can not infer, instead, why error instead of warning, and why inconsistent.

Comment: After testing more 'rare' cases, I'm not sure why it doesn't narrow it down. `const x: false = false` followed by `if(x)` does not give 'unreachable code' unlike literal false. `const y: true = true` followed by `if(y)` is also unlike literal true.  
For the inconsistent results: in the second example, it's exactly because it "cannot enforce a narrowing", that `count` is still considered `number | undefined | null`, so '?' will try to search for the `toFixed` method within `number`, which is ok. The first case is an error: it has no target to search for `toFixed`

Comment: ... TypeScript doesn't have a "warning" that's different from "error"; it either reports or it doesn't.  Maybe you want to [edit] to just ask "why is this an error" and not suggest that there is some alternative message level?

Comment: I found that when `strictNullChecks` is false, your first code works (may not be recommended, but at least it shows how type narrowing can make a difference)

Answer (score 1):

```
let result: string | undefined | null = (count as number)?.toFixed(2);
```

This tells the compiler to treat count as a number even though it was previously inferred to be null or undefined.

Comment: many thx it is a good one. It seems a bit verbose for everyday use though, but well, this is typescript, I mean just as get a nullable type with the verbose type union (instead of `let result: string? =...`)

Comment: However, now it complains `Conversion of type 'null' to type 'number' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`. In addition, after that line, `result` is inferred to be `string` (as count is assumed to be number, not null or undefined), and it allows you to have '.charCodeAt(0)' etc without complaining, when its actual value is `null`.